# persistent_volume_source configuration for Terraform kubernetes_persistent_volume when using EFS

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-efs, kubernetes-pvc, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm using EFS as a CSI driver in a k8s cluster.
I would like to use Terraform to create a PV that will use the efs storage class. I verified that I can create the PV "manually".

I would like to automate the PV creation with Terraform, using the [kubernetes_persistent_volume](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/persistent_volume) resource. The resource offers many [persistent volume sources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/persistent_volume#persistent_volume_source) options, among them [AWS EBS](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/persistent_volume#aws_elastic_block_store) which works well.
However I couldn't find a suitable one for EFS, does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using newer version of the kubernetes provider, combined with installing the csi driver (as in Shashank's answer)

example

```
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "pv_example" {
  provider = "kubernetes.localkubernetes"
  metadata {
    name = local.efs_name
  }
  spec {
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteMany"]
    capacity = {
      storage = "50Gi"
    }
    persistent_volume_source {
        csi {
          driver = "efs.csi.aws.com"
          volume_handle = EXISTING_EFS_VOLUME
        }
    }
  }
}
```

here I have defined

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "localkubernetes"
  ...
  version                = "= 1.13.3"
}
```

because terraform also have a kubernetes provider (with older version) from a module I am using, and so I needed to explicitly give a provider with a new enough version. (Sorry couldn't track down exact version it was added)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable EFS storage class like this using terraform. Also refer to [EFS provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/efs_file_system).

```
variable cluster_interpreter {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
}

variable class {
  type    = string
  default = "kubectl apply -k 'github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=master'"
}

resource "null_resource" "storage" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = var.class
    interpreter = var.cluster_interpreter
  }
}
```